# change checkbox status by parse query

Tags: swift, parsing

Please if you read this, do not ignore it. I'm facing this problem for weeks, and I searched for many solutions, but I couldn't find the answer.

The issue is I made a image button, that shows checkbox. When the view controller is open, parse query retrieve value from class to checkbox action from unchecked to checked if the value is true.

The problem when the view controller is loaded, nothing the checkbox do not change from unchecked to checked.

I hope someone can guide me to solve this problem, I will pray for him in this beautiful night

```
@IBOutlet var reqPassBox: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var proAccBox: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var showLocBox: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var recMessBox: UIButton!



    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "Checked")! as UIImage
    let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "Unchecked")! as UIImage

    var isBoxClicked:Bool!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Privacy")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current()!)

        query.findObjectsInBackground { (object, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                for objects in object! {

                    let req = objects["passwordReq"] as! Bool
                    self.isBoxClicked = req

                    print(req)
                    print (self.isBoxClicked)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @IBAction func reqPasswordBut(_ sender: Any) {


        if isBoxClicked == true {

//            isBoxClicked = false
        }
        else {
//            isBoxClicked = true
        }

        if isBoxClicked == true {
            reqPassBox.setImage(checkedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        else {
            reqPassBox.setImage(unCheckedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one think you have to check, Whether the image is loaded or not?

I used the below code is working perfectly for me 
**Swift 3.0**

```
@IBOutlet weak var sampleBUtton: UIButton!

 sampleBUtton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "NYT"), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Hi balagurnubaran, the parse query in some column is false. the checkbox should change by query value not by init set image !